# How do you fit a double espresso into a demitasse?

Tags: espresso

With lattes you can fit a double handle over the cup that you're making the coffee in. But a demitasse won't fit under a double handle. Do you make two single shots and pour the second one into the first? Do you fill a single handle twice?

Comment: Hey Max, we're happy to have questions about cooking with coffee on cooking, but as long as there's a coffee site we figure the pure coffee questions might as well come here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it turns out the demitasse fits under the double basket, but you have to hold it up closer at the start otherwise it spills over the sides a little (as in the picture below)

[image: Photo of a demitasse underneath a double espresso handle, with a streak of coffee down the outside.].

Answer (score 1):

It seems OK to prepare two single shots of espresso, then fill both of them in the same cup. It shouldn't be a serious problem except disturbing the foam form during filling.

*I assume that contact with air, temperature difference, etc. could make subtle differences, but it will be still drinkable.*